# How to use Oracle trigger to clone user

Tags: oracle, triggers, copy, clone, database-trigger

I would like to know how to use "oracle triggers" to clone a user or copy all the roles and rights from one user to other.

The procedure should contain two parameter. One source user and other target user.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a trigger for that. A trigger is a stored program unit that gets executed when one of the following operations occur:

1. DML statement on a table or view
2. DDL statement by a particular user
3. Database event

The list doesn't contain an event that triggers the cloning of a user. Besides, triggers don't have parameters like old or new users.

This [overview](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/server-side-programming.html#GUID-40297ADF-0968-42F8-B8B9-84AD6ADCBE63) explains nicely what triggers can do.

Comment: I would second the previous comment.  Even if it _could_ be done with a trigger (doubtful), it is a terrible mis-application of triggers.  Why would you want to do it with a trigger, vs. simply a stored procedure?